# Jquery Cookie plugin - multiple values?

Tags: jquery, cookies

I am using popular jquery Cookie plugin https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
Wonder how to set and read a cookie with multiple values? Or maybe it's possible to add/remove values for that cookie?

$.cookie("MyTestCookie", email, { expires: 10 });

I want to add username to the same cookie

Update: just an example in .Net [Storing multiple values in cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173729/storing-multiple-values-in-cookies)

Comment: I think you should be keeping separate cookies for that

Comment: so if I have +10 values to store in the cookie, I should set +10 cookies to do that? Wouldn't that make sense to put all values in one cookie?

Comment: Up to you if you store a json-serialized string in your cookie or use separate cookies.

Comment: Nvm, but if you just a json string in the cookie, you will get one back, is that not working?

Comment: yea, json will work probably. Just extra code to serialize and deserialize it in .NET

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to set a cookie that has multiple values or "subkeys" and have them readable from .NET, you need to store the subkey as name-value pairs formatted like a querystring. You can use the jQuery.param() method to convert a Javascript object into a querystring.

```
var obj = { email: 'jdoe@example.com', username: 'jdoe' };
$.cookie("MyTestCookie", $.param(obj), { expires: 10 });
```

Then on the server, you can access the values as:

```
var email = Request.Cookies["MyTestCookie"]["email"];
var username = Request.Cookies["MyTestCookie"]["username"];
```

EDIT: I created a test page to show reading/writing multi-value cookies both on the server and client. http://www.systemex.net/Cookies/

NOTES:

- You need to take care of escaping and unescaping the subkeys. This way any embedded = and & are handled correctly
- When reading and writing jquery cookies, use option { raw: true } so it doesn't double escape.
- I wrote a $.deparam function that will convert a name=value&name2=value2 string into a javascript object { name: value, name2: value2 }
- One last thing, the jquery cookie plugin does not overwrite a cookie with the same name, it simply appends it to the current cookie collection. At this point, it would probably be better to rewrite the plugin to support subkeys and modifying existing cookies.

Anyway hope this helps.

Here is Default.aspx

```
<h1>Get Cookie From Server:</h1>
<ul>
<li>Email: <%= GetCookie("MyTestCookie", "email")%></li>
<li>Username: <%= GetCookie("MyTestCookie", "username")%></li>
</ul>
<h1>Get Cookie From Client:</h1>
<ul>
<li>Email: <span class="cookie" data-name="MyTestCookie" data-key="email" /></li>
<li>Username: <span class="cookie" data-name="MyTestCookie" data-key="username" /></li>
<li>Raw: <span id="raw" /></li>
</ul>
<h1>Set Cookie From Client:</h1>
<ul>
<li>Email: <input type="text" name="email" value="" /></li>
<li>Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="" /></li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

<script>

    $(function () {
        $(".cookie").each(function (index) {
            var name = $(this).data('name');
            var key = $(this).data('key');
            var cookie = $.deparam($.cookie(name, { raw: true }));

            $(this).html(cookie[key]);
        });
        $('#raw').text(escape($.cookie("MyTestCookie"), { raw: true }));


        $("form").submit(function () {
            var o = {};
            o.email = $('input[name=email]').val();
            o.username = $('input[name=username]').val();
            var value = $.param(o);
            var cookie = $.cookie('MyTestCookie', value, { raw: true });
            return true;
        });
    });

    jQuery.deparam = function (params) {
        var o = {};
        if (!params) return o;
        var a = params.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            var pair = a[i].split('=');
            o[decodeURIComponent(pair[0])] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        }
        return o;
    }

</script>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        var cookie = new HttpCookie("MyTestCookie");
        cookie["email"] = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("jdoe@example.com");
        cookie["username"] = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("jdoe&123");
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
}

public string GetCookie(string name, string key)
{
    var cookie = Request.Cookies[name];
    return cookie != null ? HttpUtility.UrlDecode(cookie[key]) : "";
}
```

Comment: any idea why I get nulls as value when I try to read cookie? that's my cookie value: email%3Drrr%2540asc.om%26password%3Da8f5f167f44f4964e6c998dee827110c

Comment: I tried both ways:  string email = Request.Cookies["SolidDomain"] ["email"];
                string password = Request.Cookies["SolidDomain"]["password"];

                string email1 = Request.Cookies.Get("SolidDomain").Values.Get("email");
                string password2 = Request.Cookies.Get("SolidDomain").Values.Get("password");

Comment: I Use Json as cookie value instead. 
var data = JSON.parse($.cookie('cookiename'));
        if (data == undefined || data == null)
            data = {};
        data.font = 22;
        data.color = 'blue';
        $.cookie('cookiename', JSON.stringify(data), { path: '/', expires: 365 });

Comment: @Rbacarin not sure why you down-voted me. The answer I gave was based on the fact that he was looking for a way to read multi-valued cookies in .NET. Since .NET natively supports cookies as name-value pairs, that is what the solution uses. JSON would be fine, but you only show the client side. The server will now need to parse the JSON data in order to retrieve the data.

Answer (score 4):

Even though it's not advised you still can add multiple values to a cookie and do the processing yourself.

> *(This will reduce the amount of cookies kept in the browser but since
>   modern browsers are designed to
>   process huge loads of cookies it
>   wouldn't do anything to the speed of
>   loading)*

You can add your value using a loop and separate them using a special character like '**%**' and you can process your string on any encryption method you prefer and save all as one single cookie.

```
var setofcookies = username + "%" + password + "%" + email;
$.cookie("MyTestCookie", setofcookies, { expires: 10 });
```

---

Later you can use the **SPLIT** function to get the code into proper array value:

```
var cookie = $.cookie('MyTestCookie')
var mycookies = cookie.split("%");
document.write(mycookies[0]);
```

This is the most appropriate method you can use to process cookies, other methods will slightly slow down the page.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one:
https://github.com/tantau-horia/jquery-SuperCookie

> Quick Usage:
>
> create - create cookie
>
> check - check existance
>
> verify - verify cookie value if JSON
>
> check_index - verify if index exists in JSON
>
> read_values - read cookie value as string
>
> read_JSON - read cookie value as JSON object
>
> read_value - read value of index stored in JSON object
>
> replace_value - replace value from a specified index stored in JSON object
>
> remove_value - remove value and index stored in JSON object

Just use:

```
$.super_cookie().create("name_of_the_cookie",name_field_1:"value1",name_field_2:"value2"});
$.super_cookie().read_value("name_of_the_cookie","name_field_1");
```

Answer (score 0):

When I was using the

```
var obj = { a: 'test', b: 'best' };
$.cookie("MyCookie", $.param(obj), { expires: 10 });
```

I was getting this value in the cookie

> a%3Dtest%26b%3Dbest

So to get something like

> a=test&b=best

you need to add this line before $.cookie()

```
$.cookie.raw = true;
```