# Can I set the option raw: true when using jquery.cookie

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

I want to create a cookie with:

- Name: drm
- Value: drmStatus=Expected

I'm using the code from the answer to this question - [Jquery Cookie plugin - multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417140/jquery-cookie-plugin-multiple-values) to create the cookie

```
 var obj = { drmStatus: 'Expected' }; 
 $.cookie('drm', $.param(obj), { path: '/', raw: true })
```

However this generates a cookie with

- Name: drm
- Value: drmStatus%3DExpected

The reason for this is this snippet from https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js

```
config.raw ? value : encodeURIComponent(value)
```

This is using the value of "raw" from the config object to decide whether to encode the value. It appears to be ignoring the value of "raw" value passed in the options object.

So my question is, can I set the option raw: true when using jquery.cookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is not in the jquery.cookie but in the `$.param` part of your script. See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v963V/). The raw option is set correctly and the cookie has your desired value.

This should work:

```
var obj = { drmStatus: 'Expected' }; 
$.cookie('drm', decodeURIComponent($.param(obj)), { path: '/', raw: true })
```

EDIT: I updated the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v963V/1/) to work with your new version. The solution is:

```
var obj = { drmStatus: 'Expected' }; 
$.cookie.raw = true;
$.cookie('drm', $.param(obj), { path: '/' });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The JSFiddle you supplied works perfectly, however the version of jquery.cookie.js is different. When I tried your example with the version from https://raw.github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js it didn't work. Where did you get that version of the library from? I may change to that version if it solves my problem.

Comment: Yes, I did not realize the different version. My version is from here: (https://code.google.com/p/litepublisher/source/browse/trunk/js/plugins/jquery.cookie.js?spec=svn2794&r=2794). It seems to be an older version than yours. But it does not have the error of mixing up `config` and `options` variable.

Comment: I'm going to change to the version of jquery.cookie.js from [Litepublisher](https://code.google.com/p/litepublisher/source/browse/trunk/js/plugins/jquery.cookie.js) (which was in migg's original JSFiddle) as this seems more intuitive than having to set the config.raw value.