# Remember last state with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a script (JQuery) for drop-down list. 
How to remember the state of the list in a cookie ? 
Any help much appreciated!
Example on JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/77y7sqwr/

**Code below:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ul-dropfree").find("li:has(ul:has(li))").prepend('<div class="drop"></div>');
    $(".ul-dropfree div.drop").click(function() {
        if ($(this).nextAll("ul").css('display') == 'none') {
            $(this).nextAll("ul").slideDown(400);
            $(this).css({
                'background-position': "-22px 0"
            });
        }
        else {
            $(this).nextAll("ul").slideUp(400);
            $(this).css({
                'background-position': "0 0"
            });
        }
    });
    $(".ul-dropfree").find("ul").slideUp(400).parents("li").children("div.drop").css({
        'background-position': "0 0"
    });
});
```

Comment: when you want to remember state of cookie?

Comment: Can you please post what you've tried using cookies? Let us not duplicate your efforts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery Cookie plugin - multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417140/jquery-cookie-plugin-multiple-values)

Comment: @Mariano I do not know how and what to add to the cookie (

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I need to remember the position of the element in the cookie . To list is not hiding in updating pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i create the code with the `cookie` plugin.Look for cookies under the resources tab in developer screen. Here is a demo:
    https://jsfiddle.net/77y7sqwr/11/

Comment: This example not working. The list closes when you refresh the page