# How to read multivalued cookie in SignalR?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, signalr

How one can read multivalued cookie in SignalR Hub?

For example: I have a cookie stored as-

```
var myCookie = new NameValueCollection();
myCookie.Add("IdOne", "Value1");
myCookie.Add("IdTwo", "Value2");

var webDummyCookie = new CookieHeaderValue("dummyCookie", myCookie);
response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { webDummyCookie });
```

How can I get the values for IdOne and IdTwo separately?

All what I can do with SignalR is:

```
Cookie cookie; //Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Cookie
var cookies = Context.Request.Cookies;

if (cookies.TryGetValue(dummyCookie, out cookie) && cookie.Value != null)
{
    var receivedCookie = cookie.Value; //Here is the problem, as I can't do .Values[<key>]
}
```

Comment: Does not it work as in ASP.NET? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173729/storing-multiple-values-in-cookies

Comment: @vtortola No, it doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 4):

```
var httpContext = Context.Request.GetHttpContext();
var dummyCookie= httpContext.Request.Cookies["dummyCookie"];

if(dummyCookie != null)
{
   var receivedCookie = dummyCookie["IdOne"]; // result
}
```

I use **SignalR 2.2.1.0**

Comment: Updated for later versions of SingnalR: `var cookie = Context.Features.Get<IHttpContextFeature>().HttpContext.Request.Cookies["dummyCookie"];`