# Cookie encoding in BASE64 cannot be sent correctly to server

Tags: asp.net, cookies, asp.net-web-api

I use *BASE64* to encode *GUID* value and add them to cookie. For example, an ecoded guid value is `vClFwpDbWE6JPUlnlBXMWg==`. When the server sends response, it will add this cookie. I check with Chrome, this value is correctly received by the browser. But when the browser sends another request, the cookie value is changed to "`vClFwpDbWE6JPUlnlBXMWg`" from HttpRequestMessage's cookies, why some characters are removed?

I use WebAPI2, MVC5 with IIS7.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP.NET sees the '=' character in the cookie and assumes it's a multi-value cookie (see related question [Storing multiple values in cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1173729/59641)).

Your best bet is to store the GUID in the cookie as-is, e.g., by using Guid.ToString() to turn the GUID into a hex string and new Guid(string) to turn the hex string back into a GUID.  Alternatively, if you really need to condense it down to BASE64, consider using HttpServerUtility's [UrlTokenEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urltokenencode(v=vs.110).aspx) and [UrlTokenDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urltokendecode(v=vs.110).aspx) methods.  Those methods use an encoding which is very similar to BASE64 but which doesn't use characters like '+' and '=' which are treated specially by ASP.NET.